# Update missing cell value in csv by using another csv using Power Shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to compare two csv files of same column names and have to update the empty column values with another csv file.

> csv-1:
>
> Name,Email,PhoneNo
>
> x,x@y.com,0854
>
> y,Y@x.com,
>
> csv2
>
> Name,Email,PhoneNo
>
> x,x@y.com,0854
>
> y,Y@x.com,980

I want to compare 2 csv's and update the missing column in csv1 from csv 2

Comment: I tried with compare object and did something but i got errors

Answer (score 0):

if your email data is equal in both csv's and you want to update the phone field you can use this:

```
$csv1 = import-csv C:\temp\csv1.csv
$csv2 = import-csv C:\temp\csv2.csv

foreach ($Item in $csv1)
{
$Name = $item.name ## you can add if needed
$Email = $item.email
$phone = $item.phoneno

$csv2item = $csv2 | ? {$_.email -eq $Email}
if ($phone -eq $null -or $phone -eq "")
{$Item.PhoneNo = $csv2item.PhoneNo}
}

$csv1 | Export-Csv "c:\temp\newcsv1.csv"
```

but if the email is not the same you can change this `{$_.email -eq $Email}` to another item that is equal, like name or so...

you can take this as a workaround and change as needed...

Comment: Thanks , Your script is working.Is there anyway to update the missing  field in csv2?

Comment: Just replace  the $csv1 to $csv2 and $csv2 to $csv1